# Tomcat multi instance

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat

I have configured tomcat multi instance and Its working fine. In the run time I want to upload one propery file that property should be accessed by other users. when I upload, file is going only one tomcat. How to upload this file to both tomcat

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any automatic way to do that with Tomcat. You could implement some kind of file replication mechanism between the instances, or store the data in a common database or repository accessible by both instances. How to do that depends a lot on your environment and the tools you are using. You would have to provide more details in order to get more specific help on that.